# Creating a url instance with JS

Tags: javascript, url, instance

I am integrating a simple HTML5 virtual classroom onto language teaching website.

I have copied the source code of the classroom and pasted it into an index.html page in the following folder...

site.com/classes/room-1

This is working fine however anyone can enter the classroom at any time, I need to restrict access the classes.

I want to accomplish this by making a unique url instance, so basically if you don't have the url link you can't access the classroom. So the url would look something like this...

site.com/classes/room-1?instance=l23jhvn23o1i2un3lnj12xas

Then when a teacher logs into his classroom with his teacher name a unique URL is generated and the teacher is redireted to that unique URL instance. He can share the link with the student via email and they can go ahead with the class.

Here is the snippet of code that deals with the instance url... so what is the best way to generate an instance of the URL?

```js
function start()
{
    // Optional username and password. If not specified here, a popup dialog
    // box will appear.
    var username = '';
    var password = '';

    // The Groupworld server to connect to. You can optionally specify the
    // port number (using the format "server:port").
    var base = 'www.groupworld.net:9175:1639';

    // The object to load and instance name. To create a different "session",
    // just copy the html page and change the instance name.
    var object = 'new_conference:room-1';

    // Flags: not currently used.
    var flags = 0;
    groupworld.startup(username, password, base, object, flags);
}
```

Here is a graphical illustration of what we need...

[Teacher work flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9PhI.png)

Thanks in advance,

Jethro.

Comment: If you want to restrict the page to specified parameter in url you should use server side, like php.

Comment: What if the students spread the unique secret URL out? as @jcubic said you need to implement server-side soution

Comment: Right, could you explain that a bit more "restrict the page to specified parameter in url"? Is the parameter the instance? Also is this task impossible with JS or just less secure?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity the url needs to be generated on the fly... once the teacher loggs off the url is defunct

Comment: The best way is to generated the url in php and save instance parameter it in database or in a file then when teacher log out you will need to remove those parameters from database or file. You can't do that on the client because students and teacher don't use same browser.

Comment: @jcubic thanks for the assistance, are there any example snippets of code that I could study that might give me an idea of what I need to do? I have been studying PHP only for a couple of weeks now so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: You can generate instance parameter using `md5(time())` and you should read about how to write and read from files so save instance parameter. then in different page you read the file with instances and check if $_GET['instance'] is on the list from a file.

Comment: Great, that looks like a good way of approaching the issue...

Comment: Okay so thinking about this a bit more, here is a question... I need to change the instance to a random string... and in the code above the instance is determined by... var object = 'new_conference:room-1'; so how do I change that instance in the Javascript using PHP? It seems like I need to change the instance on my website site url and also change the instance in the Javascript that talks to the classroom host so that a new classroom is generated on their servers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a sample open source php/mysql online tutoring website for Groupworld, which might help:

https://github.com/groupboard/tutor-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have answered this myself, if anyone would be so kind as to check my logic I would be extremely grateful.

The key is in the classroom embed code here...

```js
// The object to load and instance name. To create a different "session",

// just copy the html page and change the instance name.

var object = 'new_conference:jethro';
```

So I need to change the 'var object' in the Javascript from 'jethro' (which is what I named the classroom) to a random string each time a teacher creates a classroom. That random string should be held in a PHP variable which I'll call '$instance'...

So I have created an index.php login page with a temporary database. Here is the link on the live site: http://toucan-talk.com/classes

The temporary database has the following credentials

username: jethro

password: password

Here is the index.php code with comments by me...

```php
<?php 
session_start();

if ($_POST['username']) {

        // Temporary database
    $dbUsname = "jethro";
    $dbPaswd = "password";
    $uid = "1";

    $usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPaswd) {
        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        // To generate the random string from a word
        $str = "Hello"; // word to hash
        $instance = md5($str); // hash stored in variable
        header('Location: classroom.php?instance='.$instance);// Hash is concatenated onto the login redirect page
    } else {
        echo "<p>Oops! That username or password combination is incorrect. Please try again.</p>";
    }
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Toucan-Talk Tutor Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <center>
            <img style="width: 250px;" alt="" src="http://www.toucan-talk.com/images/logos/footer-logo.png">
        </center>
        <h1>Enter Classroom</h1>
        <form id="form" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Enter" name="Submit" />
        </center>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have concatenated that md5 hash onto the header page redirect so that I now get a url that looks like this: http://toucan-talk.com/classes/classroom.php?instance=8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7

I have made another file called classroom.php which the header redirects to. Inside there I have the classroom embed code. Here is just the PHP inside that file:

```php
<?php 
session_start();

// Variable with the md5() hash code
$instance =  $_GET['instance']; 

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $usname = "Test variables: <br> Username: ".$usname. "<br> Id: ".$uid;
} else {
    echo 'Please login';
    die();
}

?>
```

As you can see I have defined the variable '$instance' again as $instance = $_GET['instance']; (I am not quite sure what this does still but it doesn't work without it!)

So I know $_GET['instance'] = $instance = 8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7

Now I simply replace the Javascript 'var object' with the variable $instance in PHP tags to generate the classroom on the fly on the Groupworlds servers!

```js
// The object to load and instance name. To create a different "session",
// just copy the html page and change the instance name.
var object = 'new_conference:<?php echo $instance ?>';
```

Now when I look at the classroom sourcecode the instance is the md5() hash!

[sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE8aU.png)

This seems to do the trick... so does this seem like a reasonable way to solve this coding problem? I am excited to improve upon this to get something workable.

Many thanks for you guys help this far.

Jethro.